# Retrofit/OkHttp query middleware or fallback to API

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an external API I query using Retrofit. The problem is that this API is costly and so I've developed a middleware service (cache), which **exposes the same API**.

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

1. Query the cache, if found, return it
2. If not (or an error occurred), "redirect" to the external API

What I'm trying to understand is that if I should, using an Interceptor, to return HTTP 302 or should I just make the request myself from the interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to cache the return value from the external API call instead of caching the HTTP call/response.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The cache itself is an external service I need to query too